# How do I check for duplicates from my 2d Array? Java

Tags: java, arrays

What I want is if [1][0] is already in the list then if inputting [0][1] is considered as duplicate thus not adding it to the loop. That's the only thing that I wanted to accomplish and yet it seems impossible; at least for me.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack; 

public class MatrixGraph{
    List<List<Integer>> graph; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Connection> Links = new ArrayList<Connection>(); 
    boolean visited[]; 
    int nodes; 
    int vertices;
    int matrix[][];
    class Node {
        String name;
        boolean visited;
        ArrayList<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();

        Node(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            visited = false;
        }
    }
    
    class Connection {
        double fare;
        Node source, destination;

        Connection(Node source, Node destination) {
            this.source = source;
            this.destination = destination;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of vertices");
        int V = s.nextInt();
        MatrixGraph amg = new MatrixGraph(V);
        int n1 = V-1; int n2 = V*n1; int maxSize = n2/2;
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Enter the number of edges"); 
            int E = s.nextInt();
        
            if (E > maxSize){
                System.out.println("Too Much Edges!");
                continue;
            }else{
                System.out.print("\n");
                for(int i=0;i<E;i++){
                    System.out.print("Source: ");
                    int mark = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Destination: ");
                    int mac = s.nextInt();
                    if (mark == mac) {                  
                        System.out.println("\nERROR TRAPPED!!\nNo Loops Allowed Here!\nAdd New Edge!");
                        i--;
                        continue;
                    } else if(mark > (V-1)||mac > (V-1)) {
                        i--;
                        System.out.println("\nLOL No\n");
                    }
                    amg.addEdge(mark,mac);
                    amg.addEdge1(mark,mac);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    
    MatrixGraph(int vertices){
        graph = new ArrayList<>(); 
        visited = new boolean[vertices];  
        this.vertices=vertices; 
        matrix=new int[vertices][vertices]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++){ 
            graph.add(i, new ArrayList<>()); 
        }
    }
    
    public void addEdge(int source,int destination){ 
        matrix[source][destination]= 1; 
        matrix[destination][source]= 1;
    }
    
    public void addEdge1(int a, int b) { 
        graph.get(a).add(b);
        graph.get(b).add(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels like a strange thing to want: what use case requires your matrix restricts its elements to unique values?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's the thing, I don't know. I just started java last week.

Comment: If you want to avoid edge duplication couldn't you check values in the 2d array *matrix*? If the user decides to insert edge *(i,j)* then you can check if *matrix[i][j]==1* (or as well if *matrix[j][i]==1)*.

Comment: If you don't know, let me ask a different question: why are you asking? Because if this is a purely academic "how would I ..." question, then the real world answer is "write a data structure that enforces your constraints". The answer to almost every single "how do I do X with my data" is "use the appropriate data structure", because the right data structure drastically simplifies all your code.